# Looping through KPSS & ADF test on multiple time-series

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, statistics

I'm trying to perform a KPSS and ADF test on each column in a dataframe. However, when I try to loop through each of the time-series I want to run these tests on, I get back a vector with only 0's. This is because `ts_station` is combining all of my time series, but I want it to be just a list of them as objects, so I can reference them in my for loop. I also feel like everything about this code is inefficient, but I'm not sure how to make it more efficient, which is where I'm most confused.

```
ts_m2v <- ts(df$m2v_mean)
ts_viol_crime <- ts(df$viol_crime)
ts_poverty <- ts(df$poverty_rate)
ts_unrate <- ts(df$unrate_mean)
ts_temp <- ts(df$avg_temp)
ts_gini <- ts(df$fam_gini)

ts_station <- c(ts_m2v, ts_viol_crime, ts_poverty, 
                ts_unrate, ts_temp, ts_gini) # *This is where the issue is* #

kpss_results <- c()
adf_results <- c()

for (x in ts_station) {
  kpss_results <- c(kpss_results, 
                    ndiffs(x, 
                           alpha = 0.05, 
                           test = "kpss"))
  adf_results <- c(adf_results, 
                   ndiffs(x, 
                          alpha = 0.05, 
                          test = "adf"))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overthinking it! This boiled down to a misunderstanding of looping over objects. The solution is to make `ts_station` all strings, and then use `eval(parse("string"))` inside the loop to allow R to read and evaluate the string as an object. Aka:

```
ts_station <- c("ts_m2v", "ts_viol_crime", "ts_poverty", 
                "ts_unrate", "ts_temp", "ts_gini")

kpss_results <- c()
adf_results <- c()

for (x in ts_station) {
  kpss_results <- c(kpss_results, 
                    ndiffs(eval(parse(text = x)), # Converts to machine
                           alpha = 0.05, # readable text, then evaluates
                           test = "kpss")) # x (ts_m2v, etc.)
  
  adf_results <- c(adf_results, 
                   ndiffs(eval(parse(text = x)), 
                          alpha = 0.05, 
                          test = "adf"))
}
```